# What sbt plugin can I use to save mercurial repo info into generated code?

Tags: mercurial, sbt

I would like to get information from my mercurial repository status (mostly: revision id and clean state), into some Scala code (to do things like println("Hello you're running version"+ v)).

Are there SBT plugins for that ?

I found [this one](https://bitbucket.org/lukas_pustina/xsbt-hginfo) and [that one](https://bitbucket.org/mschwerhoff/sbt-hgid), but the first one doesn't seem to be hosted on the SBT "community plugins" repository (despite being listed on the website) and the second only has a few scala/sbt compatible versions.

Answer (score -1):

Use general purpose tools, such as [MercurialRev](https://bitbucket.org/JPlenert/mercurialrev) (Win-only), which replace special keywords in template-file by corresponding values from checked repository

Sample from `<Some Repo>` with modified Working Directory

```
HG:REV_NUM  39
HG:REV_LMOD_N   1
HG:REV_LMOD_P   +
HG:REV_ID   dc3bad781bc5
HG:BRANCH   default
HG:TAG      tip
```

Comment: Thanks but if I understand correctly, this just generates some file from the result of hg commands. What I'm searching for is SBT integration. I'm mostly on Linux, too.

Comment: Also, with nested builds the working directory needs to be set properly. It's seems hard to do this without a plugin...